# check if entity is in context of Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

In my iPhone application I need to check if an entity is in context of Core Data or not?

How can I check this, can someone provide with an example?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information about what you are trying to do so you get a proper answer?

Comment: You have three answers so far that are all very different from each other. You should add more detail about what you're trying to do, because clearly people can't tell what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the `managedObjectContext` property of the managed object.

```
return object.managedObjectContext != nil;
```

Answer (score 4):

To check all the existing entities, you should use `NSManagedObjectModel` as follows:

```
NSArray *allEntities = [yourManagedObjectModel entities];
```

If you want to check if an entity exists by his name, you can have all the entities names:

```
NSArray *entityNames = [[yourManagedObjectModel entities] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: if([[self managedObjectModel].entitiesByName objectForKey:entityName] == nil) {} //I use this one, but thanx to your answer I knew they exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                                  entityForName:@"__YOUR_ENTITY_NAME__" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:entityDescription];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *tmpArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (tmpArray)
        {
            if (tmpArray.count == 0) //create new Entity
            {
                //NO EXISTS
            }
        }
        else  //else Update/Add info
        {
        }
```

Hope it will help!