# sqllite file showing no tables found in ios using coredata

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, cocos2d-iphone

Hi i am a begginer with `iOS` and have created my first core data app. I have created my modal and included it in the project. It does contain the entity 'CustomerOrder'.
After storing :

```
NSArray  *theArray = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"myArray"];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CustomerOrder" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

for (NSDictionary * dict in theArray)
{
    NSManagedObject * newEntry =[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"customer_id"] forKey:@"customer_id"];
        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"ExecutedOrderCount"] forKey:@"executedOrderCount"];
        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"order_id"] forKey:@"order_id"];
        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"outletLatitude"] forKey:@"outletLatitude"];
        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"outletLongitude"] forKey:@"outletLongitude"];
        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_days"] forKey:@"trigger_days"];

        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_end_date"] forKey:@"trigger_end_date"];
        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_from_time"] forKey:@"trigger_from_time"];
        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_no_days"] forKey:@"trigger_no_days"];

        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_radius"] forKey:@"trigger_radius"];
        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_start_date"] forKey:@"trigger_start_date"];
        [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_to_time"] forKey:@"trigger_to_time"];

          NSLog(@"Log %@", newEntry);

         NSError * error = nil;
        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error] == NO)
        {
            NSLog(@"CANNOT SAVE: %@", error);
        }
            else {
                NSLog(@"SUCCES, go check the sqlite file");
            }
        }
```

I'm getting this log SUCCESS, go check the sqlite file.But I can't see any tables in sqllite file. Also If i fetch I,m getting as :

```
"<CustomerOrder: 0x92ba2a0> (entity: CustomerOrder; id: 0x927a8e0 <x-coredata://49FB2963-C998-4237-BB63-5D00E2B194D5/CustomerOrder/p102> ; data: <fault>)"
```

Comment: Not recommended to look at the SQLite file, though you can if you really want to. You get an object back when you fetch - so what's the question?

Comment: You are ensuring that the database is in the Documents Folder, it won't write anything to the Bundle version

Comment: NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    
    //Setting Entity to be Queried
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CustomerOrder"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError* error;
    
    // Query on managedObjectContext With Generated fetchRequest
    NSArray *fetchedRecords = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    
    // Returning Fetched Records
    return fetchedRecords;

Comment: If I log fetchedRecords I'm getting as "<CustomerOrder: 0x92ba2a0> (entity: CustomerOrder; id: 0x927a8e0 <x-coredata://49FB2963-C998-4237-BB63-5D00E2B194D5/CustomerOrder/p102> ; data: <fault>)".I don't know what it is saying.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Core Data , which is wrapper over the SQLite given by Apple so it's have ORM architecture over it so it uses the SQLite in it's own way. Just matter with the entity and the data contain in it. It saved the data in it's own manner not as you are thinking in SQLite.

SQLite file working and making style are different with Core Data , we can use it as we want to use it. We can make tables and columns. But Core Data works totally different in the field of Database.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: then how to check whether our entity is created in managed object context or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970523/check-if-entity-is-in-context-of-core-data

Comment: NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    
    //Setting Entity to be Queried
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CustomerOrder"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError* error;
    
    // Query on managedObjectContext With Generated fetchRequest
    NSArray *fetchedRecords = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
 NSLog(@"%@",fetchedRecords);showing

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",fetchedRecords);showing
"<CustomerOrder: 0x92ba2a0> (entity: CustomerOrder; id: 0x927a8e0 <x-coredata://49FB2963-C998-4237-BB63-5D00E2B194D5/CustomerOrder/p102> ; data: <fault>)"

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
"<CustomerOrder: 0x92ba2a0> (entity: CustomerOrder; id: 0x927a8e0 <x-coredata://49FB2963-C998-4237-BB63-5D00E2B194D5/CustomerOrder/p102> ; data: <fault>)"
```

is not an error. This is how Core Data works. When you fetch an object, its attributes are not loaded until you request them by looking up one or more attribute values. Until this happens, the object is a *fault*.

If you're going to use Core Data, you should learn a little about how it works. This is an extremely basic part of Core Data.